# replace single quotes with backticks

Tags: python, html, list

I need to enclose every list element with backticks `` so that the code can be sent to the frontend. Basically, I need to replace single quotes with backticks.
Below is the list in which I need to make the change.

```
['<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <link
            href="https://www.moneycontrol.com/rss/latestnews.xml"
            rel="alternate"
            title="MoneyControl.com News"
            type="application/rss+xml"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>',
    '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rhsglTbl" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="120">Index</th>
          <th width="80">Price</th>
          <th width="55">Change</th>
          <th width="50">% Chg</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>']
```

This change is required so that I can iterate through each element and add it to an *accordian*.

Comment: Is [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) not working for you? What have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I had tried the join method. But that syntax wasn't correct or maybe I was using it in the wrong way.

Comment: @JohnnyMoppIs it possible to use regex for this problem?

Comment: Are the single quotes actually part of the text or just shown in the output?

Comment: I am actually extracting all the tables using BeautifulSoup using `find_all()`. This will give me an array of html code of all the tables. I have to send this array to the front-end to use it with jquery and bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
backticked = [ f"`{x}`" for x in your_list ]
```

**edit with extra info**

this returns a list, just like the original, but with an starting and ending backtick to each element, so if you write it to a file to pass it to the frontend, it will have the backticks

in your python editor it would be

```
['`<table ... </table>`', '`<table ... `']
```

but when you write it to a file for your frontend it would be

```
`<table>...</table>`
`<table>...</table>`
```

which is what you need for JS substitution, no?

It also depends on how you pass the data, you might just do the template literal in the frontend as:

```
tableElement.innerHTML = `${ varFromPython }`
```

Comment: Is it possible to give a sample code. It is kinda hard to understand as it is

Comment: I added an edit with more information